# Why Codeigniter Gives 404 Page not found error on server?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have developed a small survey application with codeigniter. Which works fine on my local machine.
But when i uploaded and configured it on server it is giving me **Codeignitor 404 page not found error**. I have tried it on two server. One of windows and other of LINUX. But no charm.
let me tell you what i have tried so far.

1) Changed `$config['index_page'] = "";` to `$config['index_page'] = "index.php?";`

2) for `$config['uri_protocol']` , i have tried each possible value.

Can you please suggest me some solutions?

**Resolved**
Okey, stupid, stupid me. I got it.
I was to make controller name lowercase. Like from Home.php to home.php :)
It might help someone! Thanks for your suggestions mate.

Comment: If Joseph's answer helped solve your problem click the little green check to accept it.

Comment: Are your default controller and method set right in config/routes.php  and does the controller exist?

Comment: `Resolved Okey, stupid, stupid me. I got it. I was to make controller name lowercase. Like from Home.php to home.php :) It might help someone! Thanks for your suggestions mate.` - add this to an answer and accept it.

Comment: I dun have 100 points reputation. So can not answer my own question.any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll also have to set the `$config['base_url']` to your domain name.

Comment: Yes, i have changed this while configuration!